# "Cannot not transform LINQ" error when trying to do a Join?

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

Okay, I am trying to write a LINQ query with a `Join` in it, using VB on .NET 4.0.

I get the red squiggle under my line of code and when I mouse over it, it shows:

**"Cannot not transform LINQ"**

Note the double-negative.

Anyone have a clue what this error means? Grammatically it would mean there is NO error, but I don't know why there should even be an error message then. This "error" also kills auto-complete on the line in question, as if there actually *IS* an error. So I'm confused.

Here are my variable declarations:

```
Dim dateTimes As Date() = GetDates()
Dim readings = (
    From dr As DataRow In dbReadings.Rows 
    Where dr("SENSORID") = sensorid 
    Select New Device.Reading With {
        .Dated = CDate(dr("DATEDT")), 
        .Value = CSng(dr("VALUE")), 
        .Exception = CBool(dr("EXCEPTION"))
    })
```

Here is my query which I'm being told cannot be queried:

```
Dim joined = From dt As Date In dateTimes 
             Join r As Device.Reading In readings On r.Dated = dt 
             Into DateTimeReadings From r In DateTimeReadings.DefaultIfEmpty() 
             Select r.Value
```

I'm trying to get a list of readings for all the date-times in `dateTimes`, including blank entries for dates for which there is no reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Cast(Of T)() since you can't use linq against data row collection

```
    Dim joined = From dt As Date In dateTimes 
Join dr As DataRow In sreadings.rows.Cast(Of DataRow)() 
             On CDate(dr("DATEDT")) = dt
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx#Y0

Try this (sorry, it's in C#)

```
var res1 = dates.Join(sreadings.rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                , c => c, d => d.Field<DateTime>("DATEDT"), (date, row) => new { Date = date, Row = row });
```

Comment: Okay, tried changing it to the following: `Dim joined = From dt As Date In dateTimes Join dr As DataRow In readings.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)() On dr("DATEDT") = dt`, but I get the same problem. Also tried `Cast`ing the DataTable rows into a separate variable first, and then Joining on that variable instead of on `sreadings.Rows.Cast` directly.

Comment: @eidylon see my updated answer. Try using the join methods instead

Comment: Yeah, I've moved my datarows into an object array instead, to theoretically make LINQ more "natural". Still no luck, but I'll try your new update now and hopefully that will help...

Comment: Okay, with your help I've gotten here: `Dim joined = sreadings.Join(Of Date, Date, Single)(dateTimes, Function(r) r.Dated, Function(d) d, Function(r, d) r.Value).ToArray`. It works, and compiles and runs, ... only problem is it doesn't do an outer join. I only get results with a match on both sides.

Comment: @eidylon try this www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx

Comment: Alright, here is the final code I wound up with thanks to your direction... `Dim joined = dateTimes.Select(Function(d, i) sreadings.Where(Function(r) r.Dated = d).Select(Function(r) r.Value).FirstOrDefault)`. Thanks for your help!